# Use updated version of firefox

Tags: 14.04, firefox

I was using firefox 28.0 on ubuntu 14.04. So I went to the firefox website and downloaded the latest version of firefox. I then extracted and ran firefox. However when I  type firefox  in the search box and open it still opens the older version? What do I have to do to reflect the changes?

Comment: Firefox 31 is available in the repositories and Aurora and Nightly build versions are available in PPAs. Please use them to install Firefox.

Comment: Is it possible somehow to point the firefox to the extracted file instead of upgrading ?

Comment: Yes. Edit `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop` and change the `Exec` line to point to your Firefox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to install the latest version of Firefox, you can perform the following in a terminal:

First use the update command to update your system's package information:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then use the install command to update Firefox to the latest version:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

You could also use the upgrade command (`sudo apt-get upgrade`), but only if you want to update **all** currently installed software packages.

Comment: U have the commands the wrong way around... `sudo apt-get update` updates the package lists (and needs to be run first), then you run `sudo apt-get upgrade...`

Comment: When I do `sudo apt-get install firefox` I get information that I have newest version, but my version is 42. How to explain it?

Comment: @PavelK: That means the latest version available in ubuntu repositories ver. 42. Anything beyond that can be installed using PPAs or archive download/extract.

Comment: hi. due to some circumstances i want to update ONLY Firefox and nothing else in my Linux. does these commands update anything else. specially i should avoid updating anything related to my system core. I'm not even sure if connecting to Internet automatically updated something, like Windows updates.?!